# Playframework 1.x : How to attach project dependencies' sources in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, playframework

`play deps` would download our dependencies and their sources, but it doesn't add those jars to our build path, let alone attach their sources.

How can we fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

Right click your project and select Build Path/Configure Build Path. Select Libraries tab and then add external jars. Now navigate to your jar file and select it.

Answer (score 0):

After every `play deps` command that change dependencies you should use `play eclipsify`. It rebuild your project configuration files and add dependencies.